# Is there any evidence for the theory of balance?

Tags: scholomance

El believes in the theory of balance: for every good product of magic, a corresponding evil one will be created, and vice versa. Orion, however, believes that it is just a theory or at least believed it at one point.

We see some things that *could* be a consequence of the balance, but could also be a consequence of more mundane but still magical causes, such as Orion's slaying of the maleficaria leaving an opening for some of the nastier ones to consume one another and become stronger.

Apart from such dubious cases, though, is there any evidence in the books that the theory of balance is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both books so far are written entirely from El's viewpoint, so evidence is going to be difficult to come by without opinion shading. But actually the strongest evidence against it probably does come from matching two of El's statements together.

In Deadly Education, El talks about Orion's existance being part of the balance for a group of Maleficer killing the rest of the school

> ...eighteen years ago - which I'm sure was not coincidentally near when Orion was conceived - only a dozen students came out, and they were all gone dark.

So El's offering up the existence of Orion as a wizard saving, super-powered hero guy as evidence of The Balance.

But later in The Last Graduate, El confirms that powers like hers and Orions are not that unusual.

> The thing is, I'm not actually unique in the history of wizard society; not even Orion is, really. We're both once-in-a-generation talents, but those happen, as you might have guessed, once in a generation.

So far, we haven't seen any real evidence of Balance being a built in part of the universe. We've seen co-incidences that if you believe, you can ascribe to the Balance, but equally you can just point out that correlation doesn't mean causation and none of the co-incidences fronted up in the book have to be actually related.